# Make a git branch equal to master again

Tags: git, branch

*Short version*

What is the easiest way to make a branch equal to `master` again, discarding any differences?
Up until now, I simply used `git branch -D wip`, followed by `git checkout -b wip`, but that seems a bit silly.

*Motivation*

I often have a `wip` branch alongside my `master` branch, for 'work in progress'. Sometimes the work on such a branch gets 'left behind' and when I rediscover it, I find I no longer want it. This rediscovery often happens when I want to use the branch to store a new set of 'work in progress' and I find I simply want to discard any differences with `master`, so the new 'work in progress' fits on top. Figuring out the differences is not worth the trouble: the solution described above works fine for me. Any better solutions to address this use case?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you really want to blow away the previous branch with that name, and create a new one you could just use:

```
git checkout -B wip master
```

Using the capital version rather than `-b` will cause git to switch to the named branch, and reset it to the new starting point named as the last argument. If you're currently at the desired starting point you could leave off the last argument (`master` here), it will default to using `HEAD`.

Comment: If you want to completely equals your branch to the last version of master, as master can (and usually) have new changes if you work with any project/team, you have to be sure that your starting point (master branch in this case) is totally updated with the origin/server version. For this purpose, you should update your local master branch (`git pull` inside master branch) before using this solution or to update your brand new `wip` branch with the origin/server master branch after applying this solution:
`git pull origin master`

Answer (score 31):

try this one in your branch :

```
git reset --hard master
```

This will make your branch identical to master, remove all commits you may have done, and discard all the files in the staging area.

Comment: When this use case comes up, I usually have uncommitted work in progress. At that point I often can't checkout the `wip` branch, because that results in `error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:`. Of course I can commit my work on `master`, then checkout `wip`, then `git reset --hard master`, then checkout `master` and `reset --hard HEAD^`, but that's not much shorter than destroying the branch and creating a new one.

Comment: You can avoid having to commit in those situations by using `git stash` to save off your changes, then `git stash pop` to restore them.

Comment: I would prefer git stash apply, since it does not remove the changes from the stash, wich is useful in case someting goes fruity.

Comment: @Intrepidd: Because I get interrupted while working on something, because I may think some issue is smaller than it really is, because I get carried away in addressing some additional issue when working on another one, etc. For me `wip` means: I didn't manage to finish this, but didn't realize beforehand. But point taken: perhaps I should simply adjust my workflow.

Comment: Then consider using git stash in your workflow, this may be quicker for this kind of interruptions !